# Layout differ between iPhone 5S & 6

Tags: ios, iphone, layout

So i have been developed this app using the design from the designer as a overlay with 0.5 opacity and getting everything to look 100% accurate on my iPhone 5S but when the designer uses the app on his 6 it does not look 100% any more.

It is built using just the standard UI elements and is "coded design", not been using the storyboard/autolayout.

As i understand from documentation from apple, each phone has a factor it uses to get the measurements correct on different resolutions. So if 5S have factor 1, 6 might have factor 1,5.

On the attached image the design overlay is the one to the right and a screenshot from his iPhone 6 on the left.

Any suggestion to get them to render 100% correct? ... Without storyboard layout because i'm using a third party navigation framework that does not support that.

[image]

Comment: You can also add auto layout constraints without storyboards

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to handle this one you do calculate all frame programmatically for each of your subview or you do it with AutoLayout, and best one is to do it with auto layout, you can apply auto layout without storyboards and xib, do it programmatically. Visit this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html) to read more about doing auto layout programmatically

**Update:** Your constraints should be look like this . (Try demo version) Pin left, pin bottom, set height (whatever you want) and for Login Pin right, pin bottom set height, and select both and add equal width constraint.

Your constraints should look like this
[image]

And here are iPhone 6 and iPhone5 rendering screenshots
[image]
[image]

Comment: Will try that out and come back with a accept if it works like a charm :)

Comment: Have tried adding constraints on the buttons at the bottom (Try Demo Version / Log in) with the same result as before. So that's a no go :/

Comment: Updated my answer should make it more clear... definitely you can fix this with AutoLayouts

Comment: My constraints look like this: @"H:|[_loginButton]|" and another with: @"V:[_loginButton(==64)]|" (We have now removed the Try Demo Version-button so the _loginButton should span full width.)

Comment: Okay, this will make button full width with 64 height and pin from bottom, but definitely you can  handle two buttons with constraints as well

Comment: That will cause the same effect as in my question, have merged your two images to show the effect: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2v328.jpg